# Scala & Spark: Limitations of IntelliJ IDE's "Evaluate Expression" window

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I just ran across an unexpected behaviour in Intelli J IDEAs (`v.2016.2`) "Evaluate Expression" window:

While this works, both as compiled code and using the "Evaluate Expression" window

```
  val df1 = spark.read.json("/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
  df1.columns.foreach(println) // outputs "age" and "name" to console
```

Another `Dataset[Row]` (`DataFrame`) that involves some `Columns` generated by expressions only works as compiled code, while in the "Evaluate Expression" window the following exception is displayed:

```
 com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: 
 Type mismatch Can't assign org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset to scala.runtime.ObjectRef
```

Both dataframes are of class `class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset`. According to Intelli Js [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/evaluating-expressions.html#d1669172e80) the only limitations are:

> - A method can be invoked within the Expression Evaluation dialog only
>   if the debugger has stopped at a breakpoint, but has not been paused.
> - Expression Evaluation can only be "single-level". In other words, if
>   IntelliJ IDEA stops at a breakpoint within a method called from the
>   Expression Evaluation, you cannot use the Expression Evaluation
>   feature again.
> - If a method invoked within Expression Evaluation has a
>   breakpoint inside its body, this breakpoint will be ignored.

That is apparently only half the truth.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Running into this error now, though I swear it worked for me a few days ago.

Comment: Nope, I'm sorry. Since was back in '16 maybe this issue was fixed with a newer version?

Comment: Maybe that link can explain. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634079/intellij-evaluate-expression-results-in-nosuchmethodexception, I have same issue also