# Intellij "Evaluate Expression" results in NoSuchMethodException

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, evaluate

I am trying to inspect the contents of a moderately large Scala map of objects in IntelliJ while debugging an application. I enter the following in the "Evaluate" dialog: `prices.get.keys.toList.filter(k => k.startsWith("GC"))`, where `prices` is `Future[Map[String, SomeObject]]`. I have tried directly on the Iterable without the `toList` collection with the same results.

I get the following exception: 
Error during generated code invocation:
 `com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Method threw 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' exception.` The top of the stack trace is simply the line on which I have the breakpoint.

Anyone else run into this? If so, is there a workaround?

The stack trace is as follows:

```
c.p.p.e.u.ClassUnderTest$$anonfun$4$GeneratedEvaluatorClass$10$1.invoke(FileToCompile1993.scala:85)
c.p.p.e.u.ClassUnderTest$$anonfun$4.apply(ClassUnderTest.scala:81)
c.p.p.e.u.ClassUnderTest$$anonfun$4.apply(ClassUnderTest.scala:76)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.filter0(HashSet.scala:313)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.filter0(HashSet.scala:929)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.filter0(HashSet.scala:929)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.filter(HashSet.scala:167)
scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.filter(HashSet.scala:35)
c.p.p.e.u.ClassTest.get(ClassTest.scala:76)
c.p.p.e.u.ClassTest.$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClassTest.scala:35)
c.p.p.e.u.ClassTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ClassTest.scala:22)
c.p.p.e.u.ClassTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ClassTest.scala:22)
org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1647)
org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1644)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:390)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:427)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1424)
org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
org.scalatest.FlatSpec.run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:883)
org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:67)
```

I have updated the Scala plugin to the latest release 2018.2.9 and am on the latest release of IntelliJ IDEA (from the About dialog):

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-182.3684.101, built on July 24, 2018

Comment: I find it to be a somewhat frequent problem. 

What usually helps me is paying attention when I set up a breakpoint and choosing the option to have it on a specific call instead of on "All". 
Usually, this makes this class of error goes away at the cost of losing access to variables in outer scopes, since they're not in the same thread...

But in my overall experience, evaluating future based code gonna suck a bit yeah ^^'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala debugger has some issues with the evaluation of complex expressions (with lambdas, anonymous classes, classes declaration, etc). One of them https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-14194 looks a cause of your problem because the debugger stopped in a lambda `c.p.p.e.u.ClassUnderTest$$anonfun$4.apply(ClassUnderTest.scala:81)` and the expression contains a lambda function.

The reason is IDEA compiles the expression before evaluation and it does not always capture a context properly. As a workaround, you can try to evaluate the expression from other debugger stops, for example, a body of a usual method.